# When add constraints for table header

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I want to layout child views in table header and I want to know where it is a good place to set them. `initWithReuseIdentifier:` is not a good place because at this moment header has zero width and UIKit will generate errors in log and remove constraint to return consistency.

For example if we want child view to have left and right insets with 10 points, we will get error "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." because UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width constraint is zero.

Now I see only one place - `layoutSubviews` but maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

try loadView

```
- (void)loadView 
{ 
  [super loadView];
}
```

Comment: I don't see such selector in `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.